# Same application deployed in two different servers but fetching same data from DB. How to synchronize DB data

Tags: java, spring, mule

Out application main job is to fetch the data from DB and enrich. Due to performance issue, we have deployed the code in two different servers (Two different JVMs). Now the problem is sometimes occupationally both the servers fetch the same data and process, which is causing duplicates. Now the question is how to stop fetching same data from DB. we tried locking DB rows and all, status column in DB, delay between the servers to fetch the data. However, non of them are working sometimes when both the servers start fetching data at the same time.  Please help to solve this problem

Comment: What is the database ? I find it really hard to believe a "SELECT for UPDATE" on Oracle may fail.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to lock rows. If you have fixed number jvm running you can use modulo to fetch unique rows in each jvm instance. Lets take the example suppose you have column id in your table which store sequence of numbers . You have two jvm running. Lets assign 0 to first jvm and 1 to second jvm. Every time you fetch row take modulo of id column with 2 (number of jvm instance). if result match with assign number to jvm than process it else skip it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two standard ways to handle collisions in such situations: *optimistic* and *pessimistic* locking.

> *Optimistic* When your application uses long transactions or conversations that span several database transactions, you can store
>   versioning data, so that if the same entity is updated by two
>   conversations, the last to commit changes is informed of the conflict,
>   and does not override the other conversation's work. This approach
>   guarantees some isolation, but scales well and works particularly well
>   in Read-Often Write-Sometimes situations.
>
> In *pessimistic* scenario you only need to specify an isolation level
>   for the JDBC connections and let the database handle locking issues.
>
> The disadvantage of pessimistic locking is that a resource is locked
>   from the time it is first accessed in a transaction until the
>   transaction is finished, making it inaccessible to other transactions
>   during that time. If most transactions simply look at the resource and
>   never change it, an exclusive lock may be overkill as it may cause
>   lock contention, and optimistic locking may be a better approach.

Have a look, please: 
[Pessimistic and optimistic locking](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/TransactionJTA_Overview-Pessimistic_and_optimistic_locking.html),
[Hibernate -> Locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html).

Comment: Links to external sites are fine, but you should include the relevant information directly in your answer.